# Force Http 1.0 idHttpServer and TIME_WAIT

Tags: delphi, sockets, winsock, indy

Delphi 2010, Last Indy source code from Svn.

Does anyone knows how can I force TIDHttpServer to send a http 1.0 response, instead of sending http 1.1?
I want to get rid of persistent connections (keep-alive) and also i want the client to disconnect from my server and not my server disconnect from client (to avoid TIME_WAIT in my server).

Some Data:

Request made by a client (in this case, Internet Explorer):

**GET / HTTP/1.0

Accept: */*

Accept-Language: pt-BR

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Host: localhost:114

Connection: Keep-Alive**

Response from my Indy Server:

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

Content-Length: 2717**

As you can see, the client explicity told the server to use http 1.0, but the indy server response was http 1.1.

**EDIT:**

I figured out that the best solution is to set in the OnCommandGet event:

AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := False;
AResponseInfo.Connection := 'close';

AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := False makes the server do not disconnect from the client and Connection := 'close' makes the client disconnect from the server avoiding servers TIME_WAIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IdCustomHTTPServer.pas

The version string 'HTTP/1.1' is hard coded in the `TIdHTTPResponseInfo.WriteHeader` method.

This class does not have factory that you can override so you can change it's behavior with a descendant version.   It's explicitly created in `TIdCustomHTTPServer.DoExecute`

However, since you do have the source you could change the hard coded string to 'HTTP/1.0' or change it's behavior to respond based on a property setting.

Also setting  `IdHttpServer.KeepLive := False;` would stop the persistent sessions but it does cause the server to disconnect the client at the end of the request.

Comment: Of course, merely changing the string isn't really enough. You'd also have to make sure the class *behaves* the way an HTTP 1.0 server is supposed to.

Comment: OK .. I figured out that the best solution is to set:

    AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := False;
    AResponseInfo.Connection := 'close';

CloseConnection makes the server do not disconnect from the client, and Connection := 'close' makes the client disconnect from the server. But I will accept you answer because that was that i asked. Thanks.